# download aspx page

Tags: c#, download, asp.net

HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:51659/jobpoint3.0/Default4.aspx");
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string filename = @"C:/Users/leema/" + txtsave.Text;
    client.DownloadFile("http://localhost:51659/jobpoint3.0/Default4.aspx", @"C:/Users/leema/"+ txtsave.Text);
    //HttpResponseWriteFile(filename);
    HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    myHttpWebResponse.Close();

here i'm getting the local path.. how do i get user's desktop path for any user??

Comment: sorry i don know how to do that can u tel me?

Answer (score 0):

The code is

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)
```

so your line no.3 will be modified to

```
 string filename = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), txtsave.Text);
```

Comment: but it is saying access to the path is denied after published

Comment: @Leema try to debug/print the >filename 
to see the location is correct. By the way in which OS are you running the application?